# Gitea reusable workflow Authentication Required

Tags: gitea

I have found a plethora of information around GitHub reusable workflows, but I cannot find any on gitea's reusable workflows. I know gitea's CI/CD is fairly new, but I have seen a lot of examples and successes with it. What am I missing here?

`Authentication required` when trying to use an internal repository's workflow

[image]

```yaml
# aldwund/login-server/.gitea/workflows/build.yaml

name: Gradle Build

on: [push]

jobs:
  gradle-build:
    uses: aldwund/deploy-tools/.gitea/workflows/build.yaml@1.0.0
    with:
      repository: ${{ github.repository }}
      ref: ${{ github.ref }}
    secrets:
      token: ${{ secrets.CHECKOUT_REPOSITORY_TOKEN }}
```

```yaml
# aldwund/deploy-tools/.gitea/workflows/build.yaml

name: Gradle Build

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      repository:
        required: true
        type: string
      ref:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      token:
        required: true

jobs:
  gradle-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code to Build
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          repository: ${{ inputs.repository }}
          ref: ${{ inputs.ref }}
          token: ${{ secrets.token }}

      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: temurin
          java-version: 17

      - name: Execute Gradle build
        run: |
          chmod +x gradlew;
          ./gradlew build
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aldwund/deploy-tools/ repository is private, you can try making it public.

I have had the same issue before, and have had to set my reusable workflow repository public.

Answer (score 0):

The [issue tracker](https://gitea.com/gitea/act_runner/issues/102) says sharing workflows from private repositories isn't implemented yet. Until that's done, you can make the repository public.